# launch process with fork and exec while redirecting stdout to /dev/null

Tags: c, linux, process

I have a very specific problem for which I am unable to find the answer after numerous searches.  I have a linux program.  It's job is to launch another secondary executable (via `fork()` and `exec()`) when it receives a specific message over the network.  I do not have access to modify the secondary executable.

My program prints all its TTY to stdout, and I typically launch it via `./program > output.tty`  The problem I have is that this second executable is very verbose.  It simultaneously prints to stdout while also putting the same TTY in a log file.  So my `output.tty` file ends up containing both output streams.

How can I set things up such that the secondary executable's TTY gets redirected to `/dev/null`?  I can't use `system()` because I can't afford to wait for the child process.  I need to be able to fire and forget.

Thanks.

Comment: `exec()` a shell that calls the program and redirects it's output.

Comment: can't you use `>` redirection operator as an argument in `exec()`?

Comment: @SkrewEverything No. The redirection operator is interpreted by a shell.

Comment: The statement 'My program prints all its TTY to stdout' is difficult to parse.  It prints data to stdout.  Often stdout is associated with a tty.  When you run the program as `./program > output.tty`, its stdout is *not* associated with a tty but with a regular file that happens the have `tty` as a suffix.  It makes no sense to say "putting the same TTY in a log file".  A tty is a physical device (although these days its almost certainly a pseudo-tty).  Data gets written to it.

Comment: C is not C++ is not C! Remove the unrelated tag and follow [ask].

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: thanks for the suggestion.  I did see in the documentation for `exec()` that there is a variation that accepts a shell script, but unfortunately my command + arguments would go over the 127 character limit for the first line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In child process use `dup2()` to redirect the output to a file.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    pid_t ch;
    ch = fork();
    int fd;
    if(ch == 0)
    {
        //child process

        fd = open("/dev/null",O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666);   // open the file /dev/null
        dup2(fd, 1);                                       // replace standard output with output file
        execlp("ls", "ls",".",NULL);                       // Excecute the command
        close(fd);                                         // Close the output file 
    }

    //parent process

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I will keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: @mdevico This should be the accepted and correct answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You're right.  Thanks to SkrewEverything and Jonathan Leffler.

Answer (score 2):

In the child process, before calling `exec`, you need to close the standard output stream.

```
pid_t pid =fork();
if (pid == 0) {
    close(1);
    // call exec
} else if (pid > 0) {
    // parent
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will try this.

Comment: It worked great!.  I had no idea you could close stdout.  Thanks again.

Comment: Programs are entitled to have `stdout` open and usable.  It would be better to close the current standard output and open `/dev/null` for writing.